# how to create production build in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new in `nodejs` framework .I read the tutorial, but I want to know how to create a build in node js, in other words I need a `script` which create my build folder.

I follow these steps

1. create index.js in root directory add some code.

[image]

1. then add this line of code

   import express from 'express';
       const app = express();

   ```
   app.listen(3000,function () {
       console.log(`app is listening on 3000`)
   })
   ```

in my package.json I added `start` and `build` script

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./index.js --exec babel-node -e js",
    "build": "mkdir dist && babel src -s -d dist"
  },
```

when I do `npm run start` .**my application run fine** and I am able to debug also.

Now I want to deploy this application on production Need build.**so how to generate build using babel**

when I run `npm run build` I am getting error

**src doesn't exist**

Comment: you don't need to build it, you simply need to run 'node <your script>.js'

Comment: you need webpack, parcel or rollup to handle bundling your files for you

Answer (score 1):

You 'build' command is like 'mkdir ... && babel src ....', then in the photo it does not have a src folder. So you can simply create a src folder and move index.js to src/, or change the command to 'mkdir dist && babel ./ -s -d dist'. I did not test, but it should work.

Comment: If you do not need bundle your code (which is just one file), or some other processing like obfuscating, you actually do not need webpack.